# How to set region and zone (Google Cloud Platform) in DataProcPigOperator with Airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-pig, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow

i have get problem. I will create code DataProcPigOperator before running well because default zone is running global, but i change definition region in my cluster in asia-easth1 code is not running, because DataProcPigOperator is default job running global region. Any Solution..??

```
t1 = DataProcPigOperator(
        task_id='abc',
        dataproc_cluster='abc-cluster-{{ ds_nodash }}',
        gcp_conn_id='abc_gcp_connection',
        query_uri='gs://abc/abc-ng/abc.pig',
        variables={'INPUT': 'gs://abc/abc-ng/summary/*', 'OUTPUT': 'gs://abc/abc-ng/output/'},
        dag=dag
    )
```

How to set Region and Zone in DataProcPigOperator..??

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't use it for DataProcPigOperator contribute but it seems lack of that region compared to other GCP operators: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L526, can create a ticket for it.

Comment: ok thanks @Chengzhi

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up, the region field was added to Pig and a few other job types that omitted it by this pull request:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2788